# Как ограничить приложения Android горизонтальной ориентацией

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

Запретить приложению переворачиваться вертикально, я написал подобный код и вставил в update(), он не помог, значит что-то не до понял. Вот собственно код с помощью которого станет понятно, что именно я хочу:

```
void ChangeScreenOrientation()
    {
        switch (Screen.orientation)
        {
        case ScreenOrientation.Portrait:
        case ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
            Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
            break;
        case ScreenOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown:
        case ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight:
            Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом параметре вы можете указать необходимую ориентацию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте в манифест к нужному активити `screenOrientation`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**P.S.** сразу не увидел, что это для юнити) Как написал **V Teme**, ориентацию можно указать в `Build Settings -> Player Settings -> Resolution and Presentation` (версия Unity3D 2017.3.0)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]